# Test Flash generated .IPA, using Testflight

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, flash, testflight

It's posible to install a Flash generated .IPA using TestFlight ?

I need to test my app in a few number of ipads, for private (not public) use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but there's a native extension for TestFlight provided by Adobe.

It comes bundled with the [Adobe Gaming SDK](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/gamingsdk/) (maybe you can download it separately).

Here's the [documentation](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/gamingsdk/).